# State based commands in a cinch based bot

Tags: ruby, irc, cinch

I need to have a command that asks a user questions, and records their response in pm, but I am unsure how could possibly do that on cinch thanks to its thread based commands.
Something like this

```
!profile create
Bot: Please tell me your age
27
Bot: Thank you. Please tell me your gender.
Female
Bot: Okay. Please tell me your location. Where do you live?
Somewhere
```

Etc. I am stuck on how I would be able to do this, if at all with cinch.

Comment: To be honest, where to start as I cant find anything in cinch docs about a way for it to save state inbetween commands. I cant use variables as of course cinch runs each command as a thread that gets destroyed after the function returns

Comment: You can use instance-level variables in your plugins to save state. Cinch doesn't destroy the Plugin class until it's told to disconnect

Answer (score 0):

### Use Unique Prefixes for Each Setting

Because Cinch is threaded, the easiest thing to do is make your key/value pairs idempotent. For example, running `!setup` could prompt the user to enter prefixed values, each of which is handled as a separate event rather than chained together. Consider the following:

```
# Reply to `!setup` with list of async prefixes.
on :message, /^!setup/ do |m|
  m.reply "Set age with '!age'"
  m.reply "Set location with '!loc'"
end

on :message, /^!age\s+(\d+)/ do |m|
  m.reply "Age: #{$1}"
end

on :message, /^!loc\s+(.*)/ do |m|
  m.reply "Location: #{$1.strip}"
end
```

While you could certainly chain your prompts by making each setting prompt for the next key/value pair, you'll make life easier on yourself and your users by responding to `!setup` with a list of asynchronous commands that can be handled in any order.

You still have to ensure that each event writes to a collection in a thread-safe manner, and that you serialize the collection at some point. In the meantime, this should definitely get you headed in the right direction.

Comment: That's what I did in the end, I was hoping I wouldn't have to.